# Does holding your stomach in prevent it from growling?

Tags: biology, physiology

To save me from the embarrassment of a growling stomach my friend claimed that if I hold my stomach in, it restricts room for the stomach to move, and therefore cease its growling.  Does this method actually work, if so can someone tell me why it does/doesn't work?

Comment: I've edited your question to be a claim instead of a list type question.

Comment: I actually hold mine out (as in, take as much oxygen as I can possibly hold) to make it stop growling and it works for me every single time :)

I realised this when I tried every single method in my history classes (I noticed that the 'growling' was always worse in my history class when everyone was quiet)